# wrap text in an <a> tag inside an <li> tag

Tags: html, css, text, word-wrap

I am wanting to wrap text in side an anchor tag that's inside an 'li' tag. At the moment I have it wrapping but the first line is indented:

You can see my problem here:
http://www.carrdale.com/epc/index.php

Roll over 'people' on the top nav - you will see the issue with the text wrap. Basically the first line is indenting and I want it flush.

Forgive me if this is lazy or against etiquette but I figured the best way to see what's going on is to 'inspect element' and check out the live code.

Answer (score 0):

.dropmenudiv_d a { text-indent: 5px; }

Remove this at dropdowntabs.css (line 84) or override this property.

Comment: Thanks Giogi - really don't know how I didn't spot that!! Just needed another pair of eyes -

Comment: Thanks Giorgi - can't think how I didn't spot that!

Comment: @MartinRoberts Don't worry for that. Please, vote up.

Answer (score 0):

in dropdowntabs.css (line 66)

```
.dropmenudiv_d {top: 222px !important;}
```

in dropdowntabs.css (line 81)

```
.dropmenudiv_d a {text-indent: 5px;}
```

in HTML or JS

```
<ul><li><strong></strong></li></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks verthandi - can't think how I didn't spot that!